# Javascript reference to regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that may contain 0 or more urls. I want to replace each url in the string with that url wrapped in `<a></a>`. Is there a way I can get a reference to the current matched object inside a `replace()`?

For example:

```
var msg = "Go to http://google.com and youtube.com";
var regex = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;

msg.replace(regex, "<a href='"+<blank>+"'></a>") // Where <blank> is a reference to the current matched url
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/replace-url-with-html-links-javascript/2166104#2166104 has your answer.

Comment: great, it works! but I how do i prevent xss? I just want to linkify urls, but it wont work with jquery's .text(), and .html() would implement ALL html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use [regex backreferences](http://www.webreference.com/js/column5/values.html). (Notice the parentheses I added to the beginning and end of the regular expression, to make the entire thing be put in a match group.)

```
var msg = "Go to http://google.com and youtube.com";
var regex = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)?)/gi;

msg.replace(regex, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>") // Where <blank> is a reference to the current matched url
```

Comment: +1 Your solution works. Result in firebug: `"Go to <a href='http://google.com'>http://google.com</a> and <a href='youtube.com'>youtube.com</a>"`

Comment: Perhaps because you didn't escape the forward slashes properly? Fixed it for you and counter-voted the -1